# Module not found: Package path . is not exported from package /node_modules/@types/react

Tags: reactjs

```
Module not found: Package path . is not exported from package [...]/node_modules/@types/react

(see exports field in [...]/node_modules/@types/react/package.json)
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this appears to have been caused by my IDE.

I copied a file that included this line:

```
import React from "react";
```

Somehow the new file created included the following line, which was the cause of the error:

```
import React from "@types/react";
```

Switching it back to the following resolved the error:

```
import React from "react";
```